# Error: "no rule to make target with internal static library" when linking to another same-project target by full path

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to write a CMakeLists.txt for a project.

The folder structure is :

```
root
|-- CMakelists.txt
|-- src
   |-- module
      |-- source files
      |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

(module being the sub directory of one of the project's module).

Each module directory have a CMakeLists.txt that build a static library.

The ``main'' CMakeLists.txt call the sub-CMakeLists, link every library and with the main and build the executable.

The sub-CMakeLists work well : they build the library without error (for now I'm testing with correct code).

But when I try to build with the root CMakeLists (to build an executable), I've got an error :

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'src/Physics/lib/Debug/libPhysics.a', needed by 'bin/Debug/PolyBarres'.  Stop.
```

The error is on the first library in set(PROJECT_LIBS ....)

The main CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(PolyBarres)

include("compil-option.cmake")

set(GUIDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/GUI)
# ... same for other modules
set(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS TRUE)

add_subdirectory("${LOBBYDIR}")
# ... same for other modules

set(PROJECT_LIBS ${PROJECT_LIBS}
    "${PHYDIR}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/libPhysics.a"
    # ... same for other modules
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_LIBS})

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

compil-option.cmake :

```
# ... compilation flags ...

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL Debug)
    set(EXEC_NAME "${EXEC_NAME}_debug")
endif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE EQUAL Debug)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/Debug)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/Debug)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Debug)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/Release)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/Release)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Release)
```

CMakeLists.txt of a module (here GUI):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(module "GUI")

file(GLOB SRC . *.cpp)
add_library(${module} ${SRC})

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../compil-option.cmake")
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../testing.cmake")

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../include")

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${module} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

How can I fix this ?

**EDIT** : problem solved by replacing :

```
set(PROJECT_LIBS ${PROJECT_LIBS}
    "${PHYDIR}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/libPhysics.a"
    # ... same for other modules
)
```

by

```
set(PROJECT_LIBS ${PROJECT_LIBS}
    "Physics"
    # ... same for other modules
)
```

Comment: If you build library `src/Physics/lib/Debug/libPhysics.a` within given CMake project, you need to use its short name(`Physics`) with `target_link_libraries`, not a path to its *future* location. If you have this library file pre-built, check its existence. Note, that relative paths here means based on binary tree, not a source one.

Comment: problem solved ! Thank you.
What do you mean by _Note, that relative paths here means based on binary tree, not a source one_ ?

Comment: Oops, `means` word was unnecessary there. I meant that given relative path is interpreted as `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/src/Physics/lib/Debug/libPhysics.a`, so this library could be rarely pre-built(in that case it should be located under `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/` tree).

Comment: I spent hours trying to debug this, specifically with trying to use Ogre3D, just had to add OgreOverlayStatic to the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES. Thanks!