# Specify order for building subdirectories CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a Project with the following folder structure

```
/
 |- build
 |- MyLib1
 |  |- source
 |  |  |- lib1_s1.cpp
 |  |  |- lib2_s2.cpp
 |  |- include
 |  |  |- lib1_s1.hpp
 |  |  |- lib2_s2.hpp
 |  |- CMakeLists.txt
 |- app
 |  |- source
 |  |  |- app_s1.cpp
 |  |  |- app_s2.cpp
 |  |- include
 |  |  |- app_s1.hpp
 |  |  |- app_s2.hpp
 |  |- CMakeLists.txt
 |
 |- CMakeLists.txt
```

My app depends on MyLib1 (compiled as a static library). *lib1/CMakeLists.txt* is as follows:

```
add_library(MyLib1 STATIC ${LIB_SRC})
install(TARGETS MyLib1 DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

And my *app/CMakeLists.txt* is as follows:

```
add_executable(app ${APP_SRC}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/libMyLib1.a )
install(TARGETS app DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

In my build folder, I call cmake which builds MyLib1 successfully, but doesn't install it. The error generated is:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../bin/libMyLib1.a', needed by`/app'.  Stop.
```

My Cmake version is:

```
cmake version 3.11.0-rc3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

I've already seen a few answers on stack overflow with the most relevant being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439865/in-cmake-how-to-specify-dependencies-of-subdirectories-in-a-scalable-way). But, the proposed solution doesn't seem to solve my problem.

What could I do differently to resolve the issue?

Comment: What happens if you simply put `target_link_libraries(app MyLib1 )` in the linkage of `app` instead of using the relative location of your lib? Notice that using the lib's name directly will make this build non-portable, which is one of CMake strengths.

Comment: @Henrique, that works! I also found the same suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599583/no-rule-to-make-target-with-internal-static-library). See comment1.

Comment: Cool. I'll submit as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of linking your program directly with a `.a` file, you should use the CMake target instead.

So this

```
target_link_libraries(app ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/libMyLib1.a)
```

Becomes this

```
target_link_libraries(app MyLib1)
```

`MyLib1` being the name you used on your `add_library` command. This way CMake will generate the build files (e.g. makefiles) that orchestrate your build process in the correct order of dependencies on parallel builds (`MyLib1` always *before* `app`). I think the install command is no longer necessary.

Notice that using CMake target names is the most correct way, since CMake strength is to generate *cross-platform* build files. If you use a hardcoded reference to a `.a` file, you're restricting the generated build scripts to compilers that generate static libraries in this format.